# Deleting datastore (and its content) with GeoServer REST API?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I need to delete a Datastore (as well as all its content) using GeoServer's REST API.

I'm trying:

```
curl -u usr:pwd -XDELETE http://example.com/geoserver/rest/workspaces/ws/datastores/my_datastore.xml
```

But the response I get is:

> datastore not empty

So, I assume I need to delete all layers in *My Datastore*. Fine.

**Deleting all layers in the datastore:**

I couldn't find a way to list only the layers in a concrete DS, so I did:

```
curl -u usr:pwd -XGET http://example.com/geoserver/rest/layers.json
```

that returns something like:

```
{
    "layers":{
        "layer":[
            ..., // Some unrelated layers
            {
                "name":"my_datastore.poi",
                "href":"http://example.com/geoserver/layers/my_datastore.poi.json"
            },
            {
                "name":"my_datastore.sector",
                "href":"http://example.com/geoserver/layers/my_datastore.sector.json"
            },
            ... // More unrelated layers
        ]
    }
}
```

After filtering this response to get only the layers in the datastore to be deleted, I delete every layer doing:

```
curl -u usr:pwd -XDELETE http://example.com/geoserver/layers/my_datastore.poi.json
curl -u usr:pwd -XDELETE http://example.com/geoserver/layers/my_datastore.sector.json
```

And it apparently works (if I check in the GeoServer's web interface, the layers are gone...)

**Finally, deleting the *supposedly empty* datastore**

After deleting the layers I try again:

```
curl -u usr:pwd -XDELETE http://example.com/geoserver/rest/workspaces/ws/datastores/my_datastore.xml
```

But:

> datastore not empty

So, my double question is:

1. What else do I need to delete for the datastore to be empty?
2. Is there any easier way to delete a Datastore (and its content) via REST API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [recurse](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/api/datastores.html#recurse) parameter set to true. GeoServer will then delete all the layers in the datastore.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ian. Even though you linked to workspace's recurse,  now I've seen that there is a [recurse](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/api/datastores.html#recurse) option for datastores too. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for but it only answers my question #2. Just for the sake of learning, do you know the answer to #1 also? Thanks again.

Comment: whoops, I've fixed the link now, copy paste is hard to check on my phone. As for #1 all I can suggest is looking at the code (https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/restconfig/src/main/java/org/geoserver/rest/catalog/DataStoreController.java#L199) to see what it does with recurse

Answer (score 0):

Use this curl, it works

curl -v -u admin:geoserver -X DELETE  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/NameWorkspace/datastores/NameDatastore?recurse=true